# Would like to use Bind and Unbind. want to be able to hover over other row after I select radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, radio-button

I would like to use Bind and Unbind Please. I have a table with multiple rows.  I have radio buttons for each row. When I execute the html, I am able to hover over each row and each row will change to light blue. If I select a radio button, I can no longer hover over the other rows I didn't select. please help me out

```
    <table id ="myTable">
 <tr>
<th>Selected</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Middle Name</th>
<th style="width: 10%;">Last Name</th>
<th>Active Email</th>
```

```
       <tr>
    <td><input class ="rad" type="radio" name="developerRadio" value="Value 1" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>everyone</td>
    <td>good</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>hello</td>

 </tr>
           <tr>
    <td><input class ="rad" type="radio" name="developerRadio" value="Value 1" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>everyone</td>
    <td>good</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>hello</td>

 </tr>
        <tr>
    <td><input class ="rad" type="radio" name="developerRadio" value="Value 1" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>everyone</td>
    <td>good</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>hello</td>

 </tr>




<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#0066FF");
    });
    $("tr").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "");
    });

    $('input:radio').click(function () {
        $("tr").unbind("mouseover mouseout");
        $(this)
            .closest('tr')
                .siblings()
                .css('background-color', 'white')
                .end()
            .css('background-color', 'darkblue');
        $("input:radio")
            .unbind("click")
            .click(function () {
                $('tr').bind("mouseover");
                $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', "#0066FF");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So you want table rows to change color as long as their associated radio button isn't clicked. Table rows whose radio button is clicked should have a fixed background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ye olde css?

```
tr {background: transparent;}
tr:hover {background: #0066FF;}
tr.active {background: lightgoldenrod;}
tr.active:hover {background: yellow;}
```

and bind an active class to the radio button's tr e.g:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(
    $(this).parentsUntil("tr").parent().addClass("active")
    $(this).parentsUntil("tr").parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
));
```

Comment: yeah i added the html..is there away..that I can use bind..i just started learning how to use bind and unbind.. and i want to become familiar with it

Answer (score 2):

No need to bind and unbind, just use an active class to determine hover behavior:

```
$("table")
  .on("mouseenter mouseleave", "tr:not(.selected)", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("hovered", e.type === "mouseenter"); })
  .on("click", "input:radio", function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected"); });​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc2DN/1/

Or you could return rely mostly on CSS and really make things simple:

```
<style>
  tr:hover { background: yellow }
  tr.selected { background: orange }
</style>

<script>
  $("input:radio").on("click", function(){
     $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected"); 
  });
</script>
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc2DN/2/

Comment: I always seem to get downvoted when using e.type to toggle the events like that, so I'll upvote yours just for doing it that way.

Comment: @adeneo Why would people downvote you for using `e.type`? That's madness.

Comment: I have no idea, but that and ternary's like `$(elem)[isTrue?'fadeIn':'fadeOut']('fast');` gets me a lot of downvotes for some reason? Still a cool way of doing it. If I just had more votes!

Comment: is there way when clicking on a radio button it deselect the previous radio button?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out all the strange color stuff and binding/unbinding without a live example, but I'm guessing something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").on({
        mouseover: function () {
            if (!$(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked')) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#0066FF");
            }
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "");
        }
    });
```